# How to use one type in method?

Tags: java, generics

I have two forms, one form to create user and one to update user.These forms are similiar and I want to use one type in my method,I wouldn't like to create two methods one to create user from registerForm and second to create user from updateForm

```
        private User createUserFromForm( UserRegistrationForm // UserUpdateForm userForm) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(userForm.getEmail());
        user.setGenderId(genderRepository.findById(userForm.getGenderId()).get());
        user.setName(userForm.getName());
        user.setSurname(userForm.getSurname());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userForm.getPassword()));
        user.setEnabled(userForm.getEnabled());
        user.setResetPassword(userForm.getResetPassword());
        return user;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use generic method like this:

```
    public class Test {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(createUserFromForm(new UserRegistrationForm()));
            
            System.out.println(createUserFromForm(new UserUpdateForm()));
        }   
        
//The required generic method
        private static <T extends UserForm> User createUserFromForm(T userForm) {
                User user = new User(userForm.getName());
                return user;
         }
        
    }
    
    interface UserForm {
        public String getName();
    }
    
    class UserRegistrationForm implements UserForm {
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "John";
        }
    }
    
    class UserUpdateForm implements UserForm {
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "John *updated";
        }
    }
    
    record User(String name) {
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
John
John *updated
```

Comment: so if i have a lot on fields in both form classes i should add all these methods to my interface?

Comment: I am afraid yes. At least those required to create User object. You'll have to have a common interface to use as type parameter to the method.

Comment: Thank you for fast response and for your help